# How to calculate processing time of files in jmeter for ssh protocol(source to destination file processing)

Tags: jmeter

Let me put my question this way: I have 10 files that need to process from source directory to destination directory. I have put 10 files to a source directory using jmeter put command under ssh protocol,now our system process these files to destination directory.Now i need to find out our system performance by measuring the time taken by each file to process from source to destination. Please suggest how i can achieve this using jmeter.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use [While Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-while-controller-jmeter/) to "wait" until all 10 files appear in the "destination" directory.
2. Use [Transaction Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Transaction_Controller) to measure the overall time from uploading the files till the last file appears in the destination directory

Something like:

[image]